# Using retrofit to post data to Google Form from Android and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I just started using **Kotlin** (and **retrofit** as well) and wanted to post some data to a Google Form.
The code should be simple but I am probably missing something that I am hoping is obvious to someone else.

```
class MainActivity :  WearableActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e")
        .build()
    val spreadsheetWebService =
        retrofit.create(
            QuestionsSpreadsheetWebService::class.java
        )


    button_in.setOnClickListener {
        val dateInput: String = "test name"
        val inInput: String = "test in"
        val outInput: String = "test out"
        val completeQuestionnaireCall =
            spreadsheetWebService.completeQuestionnaire(dateInput, inInput, outInput)
        completeQuestionnaireCall!!.enqueue(callCallback)
    }
}
```

below the interface:

```
interface QuestionsSpreadsheetWebService {
    @POST("xxx-dlvDQ/formResponse")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun completeQuestionnaire(
        @Field("entry.768002717") date: String?,
        @Field("entry.636841074") inn: String?,
        @Field("entry.1932913667") out: String?
    ): Call<Void?>?
}
```

The installation is successful and it installs on the device, but dies right away.

```
2020-04-27 20:49:33.095 9856-9863/? E/m.bo.innou: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
2020-04-27 20:49:34.911 9856-9856/com.bo.innout W/m.bo.innou: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-04-27 20:49:35.002 9856-9856/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bo.innout, PID: 9856
    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #4 bootstrap method
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Util.java:321)
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1313)
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:492)
        at com.bo.innout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87) 
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Util.java:321) 
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1313) 
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917) 
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:492) 
        at com.bo.innout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I am using retrofit version:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski this is not my area of expertise, you want to elaborate?

Comment: Ok I figured it out,     `compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }`

Comment: Please post this as answer and mark accepted if this solved the problem